# Display department name,the number of employees and their names

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I have two tables (employees) (departments)

I want to generate the following output:

```
num_of_employees   department       employee_name
10                 marketing            john   
10                 marketing            mark
```

so on and so forth.

I tried using this`

```
select count(employee_ID) as "num of employees", department_name, employee_name
from employees e, departments d
where e.dept_id = d.dept_id
group by department_name, employee_name
```

Without adding the emp name I get the correct solution, but with the employee I get 1 in the num of employees

Comment: department is "marketing john" and employee_name is "10 marketing mark"? that looks very strange.

Comment: some guy edited it. it should be three columns (num_of_emloyees, department, employee_name) and the data should be like this (10, marketing, john) (10, marketing, <name of the 9 ppl in the marketing dept>)

Comment: you can edit and repair it

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch the number of employees in a sub-query and then use this:

```
select 
  q.total as "num of employees", 
  d.department_name, 
  e.employee_name
from 
  departments d join 
  employees e on d.dept_id=e.dept_id join    
  (
    select 
      count(dept_id) as total, 
      dept_id
    from     
      employees
    group by department_id
    ) q on d.dept_id=q.dept_id
group by d.department_name, e.employee_name
```

Comment: your subquery contains a lot of useless thing. Especially the departments table d1 should be removed,

Comment: @miracle173 you are right. I changed my (sub)query.

Answer (score 0):

Forget GROUP BY, this is much more effective with analytic functions.

Use outer join if needed (employees without departments, departments without employees).

```
select
  count(employee_ID) over (partition by department_name) as "num of employees", 
  department_name, employee_name
from employees e full outer join departments d on(e.dept_id = d.dept_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The "classical" way to achieve this using `group by` is the following. You have to introduce a second employee table that represents the colleagues of an employee in the same departments.

Note that I assume that emp_id and dept_id are the primary keys and I do not assume that employee_name and department_name are unique. So I have to use the IDs in the group by clause even if I do not display them.

```
select 
    count(c.employee_id) as "num of employees", 
    d.department_name, 
    e. employee_name
from 
    employees e, 
    departments d, 
    employees c
where 
  e.dept_id = d.dept_id and
  d.dept_id=c.dept_id
  group by 
    d.dept_id,
    d.department_name, 
    e.employee_id, 
    e. employee_name
```

But maybe there are  ways using newer SQL constructs with better performance. It would be interesting to  test it and compare it to the other answers. It is impossible for me to predict which query has the better performance. Oracle has a smart optimizer so there is no reason to expect that he does something in a slow way if a faster one exists.